# Rigorous way to express that the limit position of a moving secant to a circle (C) is a tangent line to (C)

Tags: geometry, limits

Given a fixed circle ($\omega$) and two fixed points $B, C$ on ($\omega$). Let $A$ be an arbitrary point on ($\omega$). Let $AM$ be the median and $AN$ be the symmedian of triangle $ABC$ ($M, N \in BC$).

I use GeoGebra to draw the figure. When I move the point $A$ toward the B, line $AM$ goes toward line $AC$, and line $AN$ goes toward line $AB$. Furthermore, the line $AN$ turns out the be the tangent of $(\omega)$.

[image: Before moving A]

[image: After moving A approach B]

I found this kind of "going toward" is related to the limit but for geometrical objects. I did a search on Google for "limit of geometry object" but I didn't find any related topic.

My question: Is there a definition/property that involves my observation? That is when a point moves so close to another point, the lines and circles in the figure also move and approach another special position (tangent to something, lines co-incident together, ...). And if there exists such a definition, please provide some sources that I can study more about it.

Thank you for your reading.

Edit: I have found a paper with the title [Limits of Geometries](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.4109.pdf) but seems like it was involved with manifolds and group action. I haven't learned those things. Is there any chance the paper is related to my question?

Comment: Connected: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Symmedian.shtml#explanation and https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/tag/symmedian/

Comment: In your title, you should add to "geometrical object" '(in particular symmedian)'.

Comment: You can, of course, "algebraize" the problem so that the limiting configuration is handled via techniques from (pre)Calculus. Geometrically, you can try to re-cast things in such a way that the limiting config isn't *problematic*. Eg, in the exercise shown, the symmedian is defined as the reflection of the median in the angle bisector, the latter of which is generally *undefined* when $A=B$; however, the given context includes a fixed circumcircle, where the angle bisector joins $A$ to the midpt of $\overset{\frown}{BC}$, a defn that makes sense regardless of $A$'s position relative to $B$.

Comment: Tangent to a curve at a point $A$ is defined as a line passing through $A$ and having a slope which is limit of slope of secant $AB$ when $B\to A$. The notion of point $B$ tending to $A$ on the curve is handled using coordinates. And further the case when slope of tangent is infinity is handled separately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your observation is related to the concept of limits in geometry.

In mathematics, a limit is a certain value that a function or sequence "approaches" as the input or index approaches some value. In the context of geometry, we can think of this as a point or curve "approaching" a certain position as it gets closer and closer to a certain point.

For example, in your case, as point A moves closer and closer to point B, the median AM approaches the line AC, and the symmedian AN approaches the line AB. Similarly, we can think of the line AN "approaching" the position of being tangent to the circle as A gets closer and closer to B.

To learn more about limits in geometry, you might want to start by reading about them in a calculus or analysis textbook, as the concept of limits is central to these subjects. Some sources that you might find helpful include:

1)Thomas' Calculus by George B. Thomas Jr. and Maurice D. Weir

2)Calculus by James Stewart

3)A First Course in Calculus by Serge Lang